# Polya's enumeration theorem for edge and vertex coloring combined.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, coloring, polyhedra, polya-counting-theory

Let's say we have a tetrahedron labelled as such:

[image: A labelled tetrahedron]

We want to find the number of distinct ways to color the vertices and edges, such that 2 vertices are green, 2 vertices are red, 4 edges are black and 2 edges are white. Colorings are considered the same under rotation, but not reflection.

Just by counting I think there are 9. But I want to know how Polya's enumeration theorem is applied in this case.

In practice we can do the following.

**1** Get the cycle index for vertices and edges.

| Rotation | Cycle index vertices | Cycle index edges |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $1\times id$ | $x_1^4$ | $y_1^6$ |
| $4 \times 120°$ | $x_1^1x_3^1$ | $y_3^2$ |
| $4 \times 240°$ | $x_1^1x_3^1$ | $y_3^2$ |
| $3\times 180°$ | $x_2^2$ | $y_1^2y_2^2$ |

Where for $\alpha ^i_j$, $j$ represents the cycle length, and $i$ its multiplicity.

**2** Multiply out the rows and add
$$
\frac{1}{12} (x_1^4y_1^6 + 8\cdot x_1^1x_3^1y_3^2 + 3\cdot x_2^2y_1^2y_2^2)
$$
**3** Substitute in the colors

Let's take $(a+b)$ as the generating function for the colors of vertices and $(c+d)$ for edges. Thus we get.
$$
\frac{1}{12} ((a+b)^4(c+d)^6 + 8\cdot (a+b)^1(a^3+b^3)^1(c^3+d^3)^2 + 3\cdot (a^2+b^2)^2(c+d)^2(c^2+d^2)^2)
$$

**4** Find the coefficient of $a^2b^2c^4d^2$, which is 9

The main problem I have with understanding my solution from a group theoretic perspective are points 2 and 3, that is:

- Why is the cycle index for edges and vertices combined the dot product of the two columns?
- Why can we use a separate generating function for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: "Why two columns ?" because you try to find the combination of edges and vertices. Think like the cartesian product of two distinct cases. "Why generating function for x and y ?", read Polya method, it is a powerful intepretation of Burnsides' Lemma. However, there is something wrong here... your polygon is not regular and i could not understand how you obtain some rotations

Comment: Its not a regular polygon, but it is a regular polyhedron. The rotations are around the line between vertex and opposite face, and between the midpoints of two opposite edges.

Comment: I am not sure when i rotate it $120$ degree, whether i will obtain the same figure.